# Zigzag lines on Terrain Mesh (FBX) after translation on forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have an FBX file of a terrain exported from InfraWorks. There the model looks bright and clean. When uploaded on Forge Viewer and BIM360, after translation, some weird zigzag lines appear on the Mesh and it is shown much darker.

Any clue where these line come from and how I can remove them?
[image: top View]

[image: close View]

Comment: We're investigating, please give us some time. Is it possible the send the file at forge.help@autodesk.com ?

Comment: @varunpatil The file is a bit large for email : ) How else can I transfer the file?

Comment: upload to any cloud drive and include the link in email